# ajax loader (spinner or progress bar) where to place it?

Tags: usability

I have a web page (web app ?) where users click on some buttons and we fire an ajax call which then eventually updates some elements of the page.

I am thinking of putting an indicator (spinner) of when an ajax call is kicked in... 
are there best practices to do this ?

I was thinking to put a spinner on the top/right corner of my app. ?

is that a good idea ?
any resources where something like this is discussed ?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

I recommend looking at this [article](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/usability-tips-for-visualizing-ajax-requests/) for inputs on best practices for using ajax  loading indicators. To quote the article

> **SIMPLE INDICATORS**
>
> Simple Ajax indicators provide a strong visual clue that request is in
>   progress. They can be shown as simple text or as an image, usually
>   animated.
>
> - If it is in a text form, be sure to provide meaningful message, like “Sending email…”. Messages like “Waiting…” could confuse users. What
>     am I waiting for? Is something wrong with the system?
> - If it is an animated image they are usually represented by rotating animation.

With regards to positioning,the article has this to say:

> **POSITION** :  Whatever option you choose, you have to make sure that
>   indicator is clearly visible. Depending on their purpose, indicators
>   can be placed inside the same context as the element that started a
>   request or they can be shown in a single position for all request.

To show an example of a well positioned loading indicator :

[image]

That said,the top\top right might not always be the correct position and the location of the load indicator should **be where the content is being refreshed since the ajax call would only affect part of the page and not the whole page**. Hence putting it the top when you are doing a ajax call to refresh an infinite scroll might not work and hence the placement should reflect the update as shown below.

[image]

Comment: @zo73 can you mark it as the answer then?

Comment: I was going to but they close it. Not sure if I will bother again with stackexchange